# C++ getting some float values into a string

Tags: c++, string, split

I am on a point that I totaly don't know how to do ; I have a little piece of data (`f24.57e62.74d41.0` for exemple). What I want to do is 3 functions :

1. I take the value of f (=24.57) and return it
2. I take the value of e (=62.74) and return it
3. I take the value of d (=41.0) and return it

I have no idea of how to do it. I tried to use boost::split but if I split with the f, I am getting `24.57e62.74d41.0`...
The fact is that the f, e and d will be everytime here, any cases handled. So, do you think I can get the position of the f, e, and d with the split (or other) and then get the value from there ?
I don't know if this is understandable. So in two point :

4. I will receive a value with f, e and d which is next to a float value.
5. I want to get the float value from it.
   Thank you in advance.

EDIT : Code :

```
std::string m_specif = "f24.57e62.74d41.0";
std::vector<std::string> fields;
boost::split(fields, m_specif, boost::is_any_of("f")); // Will get 24.57e62.74d41.0 at fields[1]
std::cout << fields[1]
```

Comment: I have tried to catch te value at the right of f (I'm getting 24.57e62.74d41.0). The code is : `std::string m_specif = f24.57e62.74d41.0
std::vector<std::string> fields;
boost::split(fields, m_specif, boost::is_any_of("f")); // Will get 24.57e62.74d41.0 at fields[1]
std::cout << fields[1]
` Code is in the question post, it is unreadable, here.

Comment: Os if you change it to "fed" instead of "f", does it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `atof()`:

```
std::string data("f24.57e62.74d41.0");
std::vector<std::string> values;
boost::split(values, data, boost::is_any_of("fed"));

double fValue = strtod(values[0].c_str(), NULL);
double eValue = strtod(values[1].c_str(), NULL);
double dValue = strtod(values[2].c_str(), NULL);
```

on edit: or, as @basav says, you could use `atof()`

Comment: Chose this solution, Avinash Raj's was interisting but I need to learn more about regex before using it. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Use capturing groups or positive lookbehind.

```
"(?<=[edf])\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?"
```

Get the number you want from group index 0.

```
"[edf](\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)"
```

Get the number you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/15)

Answer (score 0):

1) Find the positions of two points, here f & e

```
   int pos1= string.find('f')
  int pos2= string.find('e')
```

2) Then use substr() to yank the characters between those positions accordingly into a new string.

```
newstring=string.substr(pos1+1,pos2-1);
```

If you need to convert it into float thereafter, you could use:

```
double temp = ::atof(newstring.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

We can just do a normal loop:

```
std::string data("f24.57e62.74d41.0");
size_t it = data.find_first_of("def");
while (it != std::string::npos) {
    size_t next = data.find_first_of("def", it + 1);
    std::cout << "The value of " << data[it] << " is " << 
        std::stof(data.substr(it + 1, next - it - 1)) << std::endl;
    it = next;
}
```

Or, we could try to use an [`istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

```
std::string data("f24.57e62.74d41.0");
std::istringstream iss(data);

char c;
double d;
while (iss >> c >> d) {
    std::cout << "value of " << c << " is " << d << std::endl;
}
```

At least that would work and be nice and clean if not for the `'e'` which gets treated as scientific notation for this purpose, and so the first double parsed out is `24.57e62`. So this is an option if you can change your `e` to any other letter that is not an `e`.